# spotify-web-api-java Invalid Authorization Code

Tags: java, spotify

I've came across to this library to get the name of the current track playing. So I thought use the client credential flows which gave me invalid username. Did a search on here and saw that you weren't supposed to use those. So I went on to the Authorization Code Flow which I've written as follows.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    TrackSong trackSong = new TrackSong();
    String code = getAuthorizationCode(trackSong.api);
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Authorization URL: "+code);
    try {
        AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials = trackSong.api.authorizationCode(code).build().execute();
        trackSong.api.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
        trackSong.api.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(trackSong::writeSong, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getAuthorizationCode(SpotifyApi api) {
    return api.authorizationCodeUri().state("x4xkmn9pu3j6ukrs8n")
                .scope("user-read-currently-playing,user-read-playback-state")
                .show_dialog(true)
                .build()
                .execute()
                .toString();
}
```

The actual SpotifyApi object being

```
new SpotifyApi.Builder().setClientId("2e411043bc7f44428f5ce91c328ac6b8")
.setClientSecret(SPOTIFY_SECRET)
.setRedirectUri(SpotifyHttpManager.makeUri("http://localhost:8888/"))
.build()
```

I expected it to go on with the rest of the program, but instead it just threw the BadRequestException. I haven't tried very much, as I do not know what to change, but I have tried different ways of getting the authorization code. Though I do believe it's due to me not handling the callback.

Comment: Have you set up your redirect Uri (`http://localhost:8888/`) in `http://developer.spotify.com` as a valid callback location?

Comment: @scgough yes i have